# Why IntelliJ displays error in simple java programm?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, println

I run IntelliJ. Simple project and received println in red.

```
package test;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Console is.");
 }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'println'...
```

I have checked that in module setting JDK is. What another I should check? Thanks.

Comment: Never seen such error, check the code correctness writing.

Comment: the code as posted is fine, you probably have some bad code in a cache somewhere where you tried to call `println` without the `System.out` part, do a clean rebuild of your project.

Comment: Try `File` | **Invalidate Caches**.

Comment: File -> Project structure -> Project -> Project SDK - is it set?

Comment: check jdk settings again. Check project jdk in project settings, then in dependencies for each module. check that the jdk is correct. that it's not some android jdk (stuff happens!). try to compile files manually with javac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to re-start IntelliJ after installing it.